# Is there any Javascript Debugging API?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I want to write some Debugging Tools. First of them would be a Smalltalk like object browser. But i need some API's to extract methods from objects, dumping local and global variables and the stacktrace.

It's okay if this is Webbrowser specific. But please tell me which Webbrowser has an **documented** API for this.

EDIT: I would prefer a pure Javascript API, but something like an COM interface is also fine as long as it is well documented and has sample code.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/216/ (Javascript Debugger) or FireBug for Firefox. Both are open source and can give you the details.

Another option is the Web Inspector for Chrome and Safari, Dragonfly for Opera, or F12 Dev Tools for Internet Explorer.

All of them can give you ideas on how to implement your own debugging tools.

Comment: Thanks unfortunately that was the reason why i wrote documented API. Firefox documentation is terrible. And Venkman code is even worse + the fact that this is only C level XP_COM.

Comment: That's a problem with developer tools in general, especially free ones.  The docs almost always suck.  Have you looked at Webkit/Safari?